# Find all de.wv articles that are not Wikidata-linked to a en.wv article

Tags: wikipedia-api, wikidata

How to find all [German-Wikivoyage](http://de.wikivoyage.org) articles that are not [Wikidata](http://www.wikidata.org)-linked to an [English-Wikivoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org) article?

For instance:

- https://de.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Calabash_Bay (not even present on Wikidata)
- https://de.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Cecina https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q157762

Could be in Python, but bash or any tool or even HTTP request is fine, the simpler the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magnus Manske's [Not in the other language](https://tools.wmflabs.org/not-in-the-other-language/) can [do this](https://tools.wmflabs.org/not-in-the-other-language/?lang1=de&proj1=wikivoyage&lang2=en&proj2=wikivoyage&cat=&depth=9&starts_with=&wdq=&pagepile=&format=pagepile&targets=wikidata&doit=Do+it) and outputs a [tidy PagePile](https://tools.wmflabs.org/pagepile/api.php?id=963&action=get_data&format=html) with around 12k items.

There are related tools if you also want to include the few articles not yet on Wikidata.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way would be to access the SQL database for that.

For that, you can either get an account on [Tool Labs](https://wikitech.wikimedia.org/wiki/Nova_Resource%3aTools/Help) or you can download the [dump](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Data_dumps) of the necessary tables of the database (here, that would be `langlinks` and `page`) and then import those into a local MySQL database.

The query would look something like:

```sql
select page_title
from page
where not exists
    (select * from langlinks where ll_from = page_id and ll_lang  = 'en')
and page_namespace = 0
and page_is_redirect = 0
```

This list also wouldn't contain pages that have a language link to English Wikivoyage using the old (in-page) method, but I believe those should be rare.